# htaccess Redirect to a folder and then rewrite again

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hopefully, this is not duplicated.

I´m trying to bring structure to my site and be clean, I´m separating content. It is an angular app, I´mean 2 apps in one domain separated thru the folder name

So I´m trying following:

`domain.xy/folder`

should internal redirect to

`domain.xy/anotherfolder`

after that, I´m using angular hashtag links and I don´t want them to be shown. When the file or folder doesn´t exist then add a #

`domain.xy/link1`
becomes to
`domain.xy/#/link1`

I´m trying around with this code, and it´s working fine if not separated. I thought When the first rule passed with flag [L] It will do another loop with the rewritten URL but Here I got the error that this is not working, and like he is not passing the first rule when I type something like

`domain.xy/folder/link1`

This is the latest code I was trying. Maybe someone sees the error in my thinking and give me a hint or advise? Thanks in advance.

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /

# Rewrites folder
RewriteRule ^supplier/(.*)$ /_supplier/$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^agency/(.*)$ /_agency/$1 [L,NC]

# Folder doesn`t exist then it is a angular link
# rewrite with # tag
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found myself with a false use of angular `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` and rewriting URLs.

I changed now the structure for the use of hashbang in my project. Now it's working correctly.

Thank you all for viewing.